# Sum of Elements in 2D array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I have a 2d array and was able to pass it from code.gs to JavaScript. The next thing I want to do is to sum all elements or numbers example in column 2.

[image]

I've seen this code while searching online but it add all elements in the array. I don't know how to personalize it to meet my needs.

`

```
var data=[
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
  ];
  
  var sum=0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    for(var j=0;j<data[i].length;j++){
      sum+=data[i][j]
    }
  }
  console.log(sum);
```

`

In my table, I only want to get the sum of Column B, and that would be 13. then alert the value or display it in div. Thank you so much!

Comment: Where did you get `13` from? Isn't the data in the code meant to match the data in your image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum the second values in each array, remove the inner `for` loop and set the second index to `1`:

```js
var data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  sum += data[i][1]
}
console.log(sum);
```

Alternatively, use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];

var sum = data.reduce((acc, arr) => acc += arr[1], 0);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove second for loop and statically set the index of B column

```
var data=[
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
  ];
  
  var sum=0;
  
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
      sum+=data[i][1]
  }
  console.log(sum);
```

Comment: tried this solution and also the reduce(). but both outputs display values in Column B of my table like this:

562

instead of its sum.

Answer (score 0):

map the data array, change it from 2D array `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` into `[2,5,8]`,

than use reduce to add them together.

```js
const data = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9]
];
const result = data.map(row => row[1]).reduce((A,B) => A + B);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

The code returns the same output as earlier. I figured because my actual data are decimal numbers. I added parseFloat to the code you provided and got the result I needed

```const initialValue = 0;
    const string = data.map(row => parseFloat(row[1])).reduce((A,B) => A + B, initialValue); 
    const sum_total_hrs = string.toFixed(2);```